# Need to match a word above and below a line in paragraphs

Tags: awk

I have paragraphs made of 3 lines and I need to match a word above and below the line with name.

The current file

```
time toto
time toto name titi
time toto 

time tutu
time tutu name tata
time tutu
```

I would like to have this.

```
time titi
time titi name titi
time titi 

time tata
time tata name tata
time tata
```

I have tried that without success.

```bsh
awk 'NR>1{if(/name/) sub($2,$4,prev); print prev} {prev=$0}' fic.txt
```

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your script modifies only the previous line when it finds a line matching `/name/`. You also have to modify the current line and the next one(s).

This script will do the requested modification:

```
awk '$3=="name" { search=$2; repl=$4; } # define new replacement
NR>1 {
  sub(search,repl,prev); print prev; # modify and print previous line
}
{
    prev=$0; # save line for next processing cycle
}
END {
  sub(search,repl,prev); print prev; # process last line
}' fic.txt
```

Of course you can remove the comments.

With the example input file from it prints:

```
time titi
time titi name titi
time titi

time tata
time tata name tata
time tata
```

Another version that relies on the preconditions that the number of fields is exactly as shown in the example input and that in every group the first and third line can be derived from the second line:

```
awk 'NF>2 {
  print $1,$4;
  print $1, $4, $3, $4;
  print $1, $4;
  print "";
}' fic.txt
```

Comment: Great, I have chosen this solution which suits well to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Then you may accept the answer to show that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is truly as you show and all impacted strings don't contain regexp metachars or backreferences and don't appear as substrings or anywhere else undesirable in your input then:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{gsub($2,$6)}1' file
time titi
time titi name titi
time titi

time tata
time tata name tata
time tata
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that includes cases where this doesn't work.

Comment: to prevent adding extra newline at the end you can workaround that with something like `awk -v RS= '{gsub($2,$6); print sep $0; sep=ORS }' infile`

Comment: @αғsнιη or with GNU awk `awk -v RS= '{ORS=RT; gsub($2,$6)} 1' file` so you just always get the separator that was present in the input. It's rarely an issue though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tacked the problem thanks to you all.

Comment: You're welcome, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
awk '{
    if ( NF==2 ) {   
        pr=$0
    }
    if ( NF>2 ) {   
        split(pr,a) ; print a[1]FS$4
        sub($2,$4) ; print
        split(pr,a) ; print a[1]FS$4
    }
    if ( NF==0 )  { print  } 
    }' fic.txt
```